# Break off new document from existing Word revision?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a Word 2010 document that is being shared and revised among several coworkers.  At the top of the document is the revision history section and all edits I make cause a strikethrough in the prior text, to show that I've modified it.

I'd like to break off a copy of the document and make fresh mods to it without the revision strikethroughs.  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can save your document as a separate file from the original and then go into Review -> Changes -> Accept All Revisions. This will accept the edited document as is and start it fresh while still tracking any future changes.